# syntax error, unexpected $end in /pathToFile on line number 3170

Tags: php, syntax-error

The above error appears whenever I uploaded my files to server, but I locally I don't see any errors. I even replaced all the codes to upload the files again, but I am getting the same error.

```
if( in_array(31, $booked_seats)) {
  echo '<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"  checked="checked" class="chkbx" style="margin-right:5px; margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;" /> ';
} else {
  echo '<input name="book[]" type="checkbox" value="31"  class="chkbx" style="margin-right:5px; margin-left: 12px; margin-bottom: 5px;" /> ';
} //line number 3170
```

Comment: you probably have unbalanced curly brackets, hard to tell where without more code.

Comment: Did you check your file for BOM?

Comment: @guido I have tested locally and there was no problem with it.

Comment: @Praveen BOM means? can you explain please

Comment: are you using short form open tags? ( <? ?> )

Comment: @guido no I am using `<?php` `?>`

Comment: Does the code *function* locally? (it's different from saying "shows no errors")

Comment: @Cranio Yes sir. It is functioning locally.

Comment: Sample code must reproduce the issue. Reduce the code to a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The error is somewhere else, not the code you posted in the question.

Comment: @AssamGuy BOM is UTF-8 Byte Order Mark. Go google for more info. I surely suspect there might be a BOM issue. So, check your file with http://people.w3.org/rishida/utils/bomtester/ or something better.